# How to properly call a interface in a Actor component from a projectile, unable to get them to communicate, Will not fire in Actor Componet

Tags: events, interface, game-development, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I'm learning how Blueprints communicate with Unreal engine (5.3) but having troubles getting my blueprints to communicate with a Interface, I think i have set this up wrong? perhaps its something i missed. I simply cannot call the data from the Component.

I'm trying to get the Location data from the Projectile Blueprint to a Actor Component. This is for a grappling hook.

I have a 3rd person character in that a Input that spawns and fires the projectile, in the projectile actor i have it set up so when it hits or collides with anything it fires off an event, getting hit and makes transform and setting it a variable.

I have a interface called Game data, and function called Grapplehook Info with a input for GH_Hitlocation, I have added the interface through the class settings to both the Projectile and the Actor component

it seems it wont call the function in the Actor Component? Image of a the 3 BP's attached

[Image of the 3 Blueprints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9x8d.png)

I expected that once i called in the Interface BP i could just pass the info through the call event in the other Blueprint and it was all fine, but it seems when the data tries to pass i just simply doesnt.

I had issues where the Actor componet was telling me that i could not use the event as it was a duplicate name event. but when i dragged the pin from the interface it was just a set node for input not output which i needed, I checked the advance boxes playing with Const, Exc, and ect what worked so far in getting rid of the dup name was call in editor check.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some fundamental misunderstanding of what Interfaces are (especially in Unreal) and how to pass data from one Object (your `Projectile` Blueprint) to an Actor Component (`GrapplingComponent`) where the Actor Component is attached to an Actor (which you have made no mention of).

The only way for your `Grapple Info` interface function to be called on `GrapplinComponent` is by invoking the `Grapply Info` interface function *on* the component. And you can only do that if you have a reference to the component itself (either directly, or through the `ActorComponent` base class). There are not some sort of a global event that is caught by every object that implements said interface.

In the screenshot, I have pointed out the pin that you are missing. This pin, for interface functions, is `DefaultToSelf` in Unreal but that's not always what you want. This pin must instead be conneted to the Actor Component.

[image]

In fact, you can even see on your interface function call, it says **Target is Grappling Hook Projectile BP**.

[image]

Moreover, interface functions should generally be called through their `Message` variant. For example, the following screenshot shows the interface call `My Function` as a message (envelope icon)

[image]

To sum up:

- you need the reference to the ActorComponent (GrapplingComponent) through the Actor on which it has been added
- the reference must be either stored on `Projectile_BP` or `Projectile_BP` needs to be able to get the reference somehow
- invoke the interface function on the ActorComponent through the `Projectile_BP` by connecting the above mentioned pin to the component reference

Comment: This has solved my issue, your right i was missing my Target! I was able to communicate my data to my component once i linked the target and get refrence.